# Combine Two data frames if values on one column is equal

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, data-preprocessing

I need to combine two dataframes where they have similar columns however the 1st dataframe is missing one column i need to add values from 2nd dataframe to 1st

```
display(df)
```

| id | TITLE | CODE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 12 | 125 |
| 2 | Katie | 14 | 325 |
| 4 | Janie | 24 | 550 |
| 5 | Jacob | 32 | 500 |
| 6 | John | 42 | 400 |

```
display(df2)
```

| id | TITLE | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | John | 12 |
| 8 | Katie | 14 |
| 9 | John | 42 |
| 10 | Janie | 50 |
| 11 | Elle | 32 |
| 12 | John | 42 |

Required Output:

| id | TITLE | CODE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | John | 12 | 125 |
| 8 | Katie | 14 | 325 |
| 9 | John | 42 | 400 |
| 10 | Janie | 50 | Nan |
| 11 | Elle | 32 | Nan |
| 12 | John | 42 | 400 |

Comment: One way is to use a merge: `df2.merge(df.drop(columns="id"), on=["TITLE", "CODE"], how="left")`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df2.merge(df[['TITLE', 'CODE', 'PRICE']], on=['CODE', 'TITLE'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
   id  TITLE  CODE  PRICE
0   7   John    12  125.0
1   8  Katie    14  325.0
2   9   John    42  400.0
3  10  Janie    50    NaN
4  11   Elle    32    NaN
5  12   John    42  400.0
```